# Why is my Scenario Outline not getting called in SpecFlow?

Tags: .net, specflow

I am having a Scenario Outline as follows:

```
Scenario Outline: Create Request Custom Export With XML, Comma Delimited, Tab Delimited 
    Given a user has entered the following data
    | Custom Export     | File Format       | Vendor                 |
    |  Custom Export 1  | <File  Format>    | 001_TestsVendor_Rp     |    
    When I save
    Examples: 
    | File Format     |
    | XML             |
    | Comma Delimited |
    | Tab Delimited   |
```

But when I Run the scenario, Scenario outline is not getting called. But a normal scenario is running well.Is there any modification needed in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your valuable responses. I got my problem fixed by installing **Resharper** software. I don't how it helps to run scenario outline. But it made me breathe easier. If any one got into such problem make a try on **Resharper**.

Thanks.

Comment: It didn't help me but :P

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simply because your scenario outline column `<Format>` does not match your examples column `File Format` ?

I would also question if you really need to use a table in the outline, it might read better if you used

```
Given we are using a custom export of type Custom Export 1
And a <Format> file format
And vendor 001_TestsVendor_Rp
```

Comment: Sorry, Now I have edited correct code. Though, my scenario outline is not even getting called. Given statement is also not working. But a normal Scenario is running as expected. If Scenario Outline itself not getting recognised how can the table can be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Specflow Visual Studio Plugin?
Are you using Regex attributes as method bindings?
Can you post your method bindings Given/When syntax?

Can you see that Specflow has picked up the steps in your feature file, they should black.
If they are purple-ish, it can't find the associated step.

If you've been refactoring, close and open the project again.
I've had issues with the Specflow plugin where it couldn't pickup new methods after refactoring.

I haven't got to the bottom of why yet but thats a quick fix.